# Is sending message to a non-existent window Ok?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a thread that send update messages to a window, I use `::SendMessage()` and `::PostMessage()` APIs.

I go in and out of multiple dialogs and register the dialog that I am currently in with the thread via the window handle (`m_hWnd`). If I exit all the way out, the main application window doesn't handle these messages. For that reason I don't register that window. At this point the thread will have the handle of an older window which now doesn't exist.

Is it okay if it sends messages to that non-existent window? I am assuming it should not do any harm but wanted to double check.

Comment: Is sending message to a NULL window okay than? I don't want unnecessary `if-else`statements but I could set the window handle to NULL in the thread where all messages will be directed to.

Comment: @Deduplicator Don't know why people vote down a legit question? In Objective-C you can call any method on any object for that matter and calling methods on NULL objects is commonly used trick (if I remember currently)

Comment: It happens. Anyway, this one could be made clearer. The Wall of Text in the body is a bit repellent... Still, made me look at things anew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not ok to post a message to a deleted window.
There is no guarantee noone will set up shop at that address just after the previous tennant is gone.

If you use a `NULL` window handle, you'll post a thread message to the current threads message queue. `SendMessage` as far as I could google shoul be a no-op.
Might be harmless enough.

Now, we get tricky:

Under specific cicumstances it does not matter, pre-supposing well-behaved applications.

1. A message like `WM_NULL` should not make anything happen.
2. A window-message you globally registered in your application using [RegisterWindowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you can guarantee none of your applications windows created in the meantime will choke on it.

Comment: The problem with handle recycling was an issue for 16-bit Windows but not an issue since WinNT although MS doesn't like it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070717-00/?p=25983/